# WP_Query tax query part of slug

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, slug, tax-query

I have problem with filtering post with tax query.
I have a custom taxonomy called 'actors' and example of the slug is 'david-hasselhoff'. The problem is the post is found when I search with 'david hasselhof', but not with 'david' or 'hasselhof'.

Here is my code so far

```php
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'actors',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $keyword,
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to search in taxonomy. First using `name__like` in `get_terms` it will return all terms ids which have $keyword then that ids use in `wp_query`.

```
$termIds = get_terms([
    'name__like' => $keyword,
    'fields' => 'ids'
]);
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'actors',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $termIds,
        ]
    ]
];

$query_loop = new WP_Query($args);
```